# Highlight Last Number Called

Tags: c#

I have created a Bingo machine that calls and checks numbers that have been called. Once a user calls house the game will be paused and a separate form will be used to check the numbers. This separate form has numbers from 1-90 and will all be highlighted. My question is, how do I highlight the LAST number that has been called out?

Code for all numbers called to be highlighted:

```
private void btnCheckNumbs_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Check to see what numbers have been called by calling on Global Variables. 
    for (int i = 1; i <= Globals.NextBalls; i++)
    {

        for (int k = 1; k <= 90; k++)
        {
            if (Globals.balls[i] == k)
            {
                TextBox txtName = (TextBox)this.Controls.Find("txtBoxs" + k.ToString(), true)[0];
                txtName.BackColor = Color.Crimson;

            }
        }
    }
```

This is the code for Next Balls, Basically txtBoxMainNo is the text box that displays the last number to be called out.

```
 // Timer of the game

    private void GameTimer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Globals.balls[1] = 1;
        txtboxMainNo.Text = Convert.ToString(Globals.balls[Globals.NextBalls]);
        Globals.NextBalls = Globals.NextBalls + 1;
        SpVoice obj = new SpVoice();

        int i = Convert.ToInt32(txtboxMainNo.Text);
        obj.Speak(Globals.bingocomments[i], SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags.SVSFDefault);

        if (Globals.NextBalls >= 91) { GameTimer1.Enabled = false; }
    }
```

Comment: This is ``C#`` not `java`

Comment: I don't know how that changed to Java as I selected C# Tag.

Comment: @nathancording You put Java in the title, so someone "fixed" it for you by removing it and updating your tags.

Comment: What does `Globals.NextBalls` contain?

Comment: @DavidArno Hi, I have added code to my main version to show you what Next Balls does. hope you could help me. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hey if you just want to highlight the last Element, I'd just add a List and get the last index. Then highlight the color of that element.

```
 private void btnCheckNumbs_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var list = new List<TextBox>();
            //Check to see what numbers have been called by calling on Global Variables. 
            for (int i = 1; i <= Globals.NextBalls; i++)
            {

                for (int k = 1; k <= 90; k++)
                {
                    if (Globals.balls[i] == k)
                    {
                        TextBox txtName = (TextBox) this.Controls.Find("txtBoxs" + k.ToString(), true)[0];
                        list.Add(txtName);

                    }
                }
            }
        list.Last().BackColor = Color.Crimson;
        }
```

Comment: Hi i just used this method, but some how when i call the number its not the number that is displayed in my label. It highlights the number that is going to be called next. How do I simply highlight the number that's displayed in the label. Thank you.

Comment: You could try to exchange "list.Last().BackColor = Color.Crimson;" to "list[list.Count -2].BackColor = Color.Crimson;" If that does not work message me and send me your project then I can fix it for you.